# What is the difference between "archetype" and "prototype"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, ambiguity

I'm very confused by the difference between "archetype" and "prototype", and even more baffled when to use which. Can someone clarify?

Comment: And don't forget "stereotype", which is similar to both!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I will disagree with Robusto and Mr. Disappointment insomuch that the two words have very different meanings. This is copied from my local dictionary and I think it describes the difference well:

> While *prototype* and *archetype* are often used interchangeably, they really mean quite different things. An *archetype* is a perfect and unchanging form that existing things or people can approach but never duplicate (*: the archetype of a mother*), while a *prototype* is an early, usually unrefined version of something that later versions reflect but may depart from (*: a prototype for a hydrogen-fueled car*).

In other words, a *prototype* is a (usually physical) draft. An *archetype* is an ideal example or theoretical perfect form. Something could correctly be labeled *both* a prototype and archetype but generally prototypes are inferior to the final product. Their very label of prototype implies that it will be replaced with a different form later in the design process.

The final prototype can be considered the primary modeling example if the object is intended for mass production and a *loose* usage of "archetype" could apply. Then the meaning would shift from focusing on the prototype and, instead, focusing on the reproductions. As in, the reproductions better faithfully mimic the *archetype* because if they didn't than the process is flawed. This usage holds no implications about the perfection of the archetype and, therefore, I consider *prototype* the appropriate word.

Even the other dictionary examples posted in the other examples are not suggesting they are synonyms:

> prototype - a first or primitive form
>
> archetype - original pattern from which copies are made

"First form" and "original pattern" are *similar* but their usages are drastically different.

> archetype - an original model or type after which other similar things are patterned; a prototype

Using "prototype" to describe "archetype" *works* but the usage example helps reveals the difference:

> "'Frankenstein' ... 'Dracula' ... 'Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde' ... the archetypes that have influenced all subsequent horror stories" (New York Times).

"Prototype" would be incorrect in that sentence. Here is the same dictionary's definition of *prototype*:

> prototype - an original type, form, or instance serving as a basis or standard for later stages.

The difference in meaning is again hard to see but *prototype* is a staged type or form: It is "original" in the sense that it came before the next one in sequence. "Archetype" is "original" in the sense that there wasn't anything else before it. You can (and usually do) have a sequence of prototypes; you generally only have one archetype.

Answer (score 16):

They are, for a lot of purposes, synonymous - both coming from Greek and being carried through the years, both referring to an initial foundation, a typical example of something or other.

The difference I would pick up on is that *archetype* has the benefit of being considered an ideal mould - that is, a fundamental basis which should be taken as an example in future considerations, improvements to the model being few and far between and exclusions of existing features unheard of - whereas *prototype* could simply be the first mould, for all it works as expected, may be subject to improvement and, in fact, possibly some implementation of it being wrong and in need of correction.

> **Prototype**
>
> [OED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prototype):
>   c.1600, from Fr. prototype, from M.L.
>   prototypon, from Gk. prototypon "a
>   first or primitive form," properly
>   neut. sing. of prototypos "original,
>   primitive," from protos "first" (see
>   proto-) + typos "impression" (see
>   type).
>
> [ThreFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prototype): *[French, from Greek prtotupon, from
>   neuter of prtotupos, original : prto-,
>   proto- + tupos, model.]*
>
> **Archetype**
>
> [OED](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=archetype):
>   "original pattern from which copies
>   are made," 1540s, from L. archetypum,
>   from Gk. arkhetypon "pattern, model,
>   figure on a seal," neut. of adj.
>   arkhetypos "first-moulded," from
>   arkhe- "first" (see archon) + typos
>   "model, type, blow, mark of a blow"
>   (see type). Jungian psychology sense
>   of "pervasive idea or image from the
>   collective unconscious" is from 1919.
>
> [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/archetype): 
>   *[Latin archetypum, from Greek
>   arkhetupon, from neuter of arkhetupos,
>   original : arkhe-, arkhi-, archi- +
>   tupos, model, stamp.]*

Comment: As far as I know "archetype" can refer to an idealized, inexistent example, whereas a "prototype" is a concrete, existing example.

Comment: I fail to see what is 'typical' about a *prototype*, in the usual sense of the word *typical*. The *prototype* aeroplane flown by the Wright brothers didn't even have jet engines! The current *archetype* does.

Answer (score 8):

The two words are synonymous, but I mostly hear *archetype* used in [this sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/archetype):

> 2: An ideal example of a type; quintessence: *an archetype of the successful entrepreneur*.

And *prototype* seems mainly used in [this sense](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prototype):

> 2: An original, full-scale, and usually working model of a new product or new version of an existing product.

I realize that each of these represents the second entry in its second definition, but that's what I hear most often.

EDIT Markdown issue fixed. Thanks, @Alenanno.

Comment: You're welcome! I see what you mean, but at the moment I am not aware of any workaround for that.

Comment: You can put the HTML entity `&#8203;` before the number, representing a "zero-width space".  This will prevent Markdown from identifying it as a list, so it will leave your number (and the following period) alone.

Comment: I fail to see any similarity whatever between the meaning of the two words, other than that they are both suffixed *...type*. And they are both *types*. But they are quite different *types*. If Henry Ford was the *archetype* of the successful entrepreneur, the *prototype* will have lived in ancient China or Babylonia!

Comment: @WS2: You're confusing me with the OP. Your beef is with him, not me.

Comment: @Robusto I'm commenting on what was written by you when you said the two words were synonymous.

Comment: That's referring to usage, which is what appeared to be confusing the OP. I'm not responsible for that either, though I appear to have been trying to bring the OP along somewhat more gently. I'm not even sure what I was thinking after four years.

Answer (score 5):

They are not synonymous. An [archetype](http://www.beedictionary.com/definition/archetype) is replicated as is and a [prototype](http://www.beedictionary.com/definition/prototype) is normally improved upon.

Answer (score 5):

A *prototype* is an attempt at something. An *archetype* is the most perfect possible form of something. They are *opposites*.

Comment: Short and to the point. All the other answers waste screen estate giving further details of exactly what the two words mean in other contexts, but when they're actually being juxtaposed this way (or worse, being considered in order to decide which one to use), you really need to emphasise the sense in which they are **OPPOSITES**!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is over simplified, but *archetype* is the concept of something, and *prototype* is an evolving instance of it.