# What does "stereotype" mean in: "this movement is very fast, stereotype and for a short duration"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Please tell me the meaning of *stereotype* in the following passage

> Reflexes: This is the behaviour in which movement takes place in a particular organ. This movement is very fast, stereotype, and for a short duration such as knee jerk, blinking of eyes and withdrawal of hand from a hot place".

This is a behavioral science term, not sociological.

**Edit:** Thank you everyone for the reply. Finally I got the answer from Britannica - [Stereotyped response](http://www.britannica.com/topic/stereotyped-response)

Comment: That depends: do you mean as a noun or as a verb? What definition did you find for it?

Comment: Can you provide the meaning which was given in the dictionary and tell why you didn't understand the meaning? Stereotype basically means a widely held fixed opinion about a person or a thing. You most often hear negative stereotype, like *All women are bad drivers* which is not true. There are also positive stereotypes. It is just a preconceived notion.

Comment: ***Stereotype***: a fixed idea or image that many people have of a particular type of person or thing, but which is often not true in reality
cultural/gender/racial stereotypes:
*He doesn't conform to the usual stereotype of the businessman with a dark suit and briefcase.* http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/stereotype_1

Comment: As a corollary to what @Josh61 provided, it can be used as a verb meaning "view or represent as a stereotype.": *You shouldn't stereotype the Irish; they're not all drunks.*

Comment: Thank you for adding the context. What is the name of the textbook, and where and when was it published? The wording is a little bit stilted overall (*withdrawal of hand*?), so it may well be an error on the author or editors' part, especially if they are not native speakers, with some other word or phrase intended.

Comment: The author probably wants to say that the muscle reflexes are automatic, and easily predictable, they conform to the stereotype of muscle contractions. But that sentence sounds a bit odd, who is the author? Was the book by any chance translated into English?

Comment: Searching Google for the quoted passage finds only this question. Is it transcribed correctly? Is it actually written in English or is this a translation? Please provide a reference (book title and author at a minimum).

Comment: You're all looking at the sociological meaning of the word *stereotype*, but the quotation shows that it is the zoological sense that is being queried.  I have an answer, but we need to re-open it so that I can post it.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Surely the word should be *stereotypical*? *Stereotype* can't be an adjective like this.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, *stereotypical* is still sociological, and if the quote is accurate would still not fit in the sentence.  I believe the quoted text should have substituted the word *stereotypy* for *stereotype*, but in any case it is not using the word as most of us are understanding it.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Well, I'm intrigued, because *stereotypy* is an odd word (is that *-typy* "like a stereotype", similar to *briny* "like brine"?)

Comment: @AndrewLeach: it might be odd, but it's real.  It's a noun, so doesn't fit the sentence very well, but it's distinct from the sociological sense, at least.  *Stereotypical* is actually OK, but its not the same *stereotypical* as in sociology.  My source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypy_(non-human)

Comment: In context, "stereotype" is a typo, it should be "stereotyped" or stereotypical".

Comment: What is the title of the book, please? Does the excerpt refer to zoology? Animal behaviour? Is it describing a neurosis?

Answer (score 2):

@GEdgar got it before me, but yes, that's what it means here in context!

The noun for this is *[stereotypy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotypy_(non-human))*:

> In animal behavior, stereotypy, stereotypical or stereotyped behavior
>   has several meanings, leading to ambiguity in the scientific
>   literature. The terms usually refer to stereotypy, repetitive
>   behaviors in captive animals, particularly those given inadequate
>   mental stimulation.

It's also described for human use [HERE](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/stereotypy) in the Free Dictionary.

Comment: You know... I don't think this is the right answer. Knee jerks, eye blinking, backing away from fire all "fast" reactions, perfectly normal among all species, and are usually described as "reflexes". There's nothing abnormal or obsessively repetitive about these "instinctual" movements.

Comment: @Mari-LouA you might be right about the correct usage of stereotypy in the quoted text -- that's a technical matter with respect to the book in which the quote is found. But I still maintain that the usage, as such, is referring to stereotypy.  Regardless of whether the quote is telling the truth.  We're not judging the validity of the text, but rather what it means.

Answer (score 1):

*Oxford English Dictionary*

> **stereotype**, *n.* and *adj.*
>   A. *n.*
>   3. *fig.*
>   c. *Zool.* A stereotyped action or series of actions performed by an animal

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I think the original quoted text, if an accurate quote, uses the term *stereotype* incorrectly, i.e. as a noun.  It probably should have been *stereotypical*, the adjectival form.  See my answer for some detail and reference to Wikipedia on the subject.  Stereotypy is the zoological term for the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to understand the word stereotype used in sociology, let me  quote from [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/91105/107386):

> stereotype - is a preconceived and oversimplified idea of the
>   characteristics which typify a person, situation, etc.; an attitude
>   based on such a preconception. Also, a person who appears to conform
>   closely to the idea of a type.

I prefer not to be known by my friends to be using stereotypes rather than studying and analyzing the facts closely. It is when one classifies a group of people or things, and this can make the picture one has of that group quite inaccurate.

It can be used as a noun or a verb. Example for stereotype as a [verb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stereotype): "to form a fixed and often untrue or only partly true idea about". You can also '*stereotype*' a group of people '*with*' an assumption.

> It's unfair to stereotype people according to where they live.
>
> It's not fair to stereotype a whole group of people based on one
>   person you don't like.
>
> Movies have stereotyped the hooker with a heart of gold ad nauseam.

Example as a noun and this is quoting from Dictionary.com:

> The black community cannot pretend that the stereotype of black men as
>   violent comes out of nowhere.

Sometimes looking at the adjective or derivatives would help understand and use the a term correctly.

Quoting from Urban Dictionary about Stereotypical:

> A stereotypical person is one who is the image of a stereotype. It is
>   NOT (I repeat, NOT!!!!) a person who believes that stereotypes are
>   true. Only a stereotypical foreigner would think this, because the
>   stereotype of foreigners is that they are bad at English.