# Adjective which means both "Specific" and "General" simultaneously

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, adjectives, phrase-requests, vocabulary

I need an adjective which means both "Specific" and "General" simultaneously!

As the explanation,  the "adjective" is supposed to be used in scientific domain. 
The adjective would describes a "model" representing a group of data instances so that the model is:

1) "specific" enough to distinguish the group from other groups.

2) "general" enough to capture all shared commonalities of its included instances.

So, the model is a "??????" model!

As an example for the word that I mean:

Consider we have resume (list of abilities) of 5 people (call theme A-E) like this:

A,B:[Programming, Speaking Dutch Language, Playing Guitar]

C:[Programming, Team Working, Speaking Dutch Language]

E,F:[Team Working, Speaking Dutch Language].

The A, B and C form the group X together and C, D and E form another group, say Y. We want to find a ``specific'' list of abilities for group X which contain common abilities of its members. So, a "general" and "specific" list would contain "Programming" but not "Dutch Language". Since "Dutch language" although is a share ability among A,B and C, it is a share ability between the members group Y.
The adjective that I need should describe the [Programming] as the list of abilities (as the model of) group X, which is just describe the group X (not other group) -specified- and also describe share property of its members -generalised-.

I hope this example would help!

Comment: Inventing a new word would also be nice if somebody has any idea :)

Comment: Can you translate it into an everyday setting, using everyday objects like knives and forks? Perhaps blue pens, red pens and yellow pens; or jelly babies or something?

Comment: Isn't this basically implied in the concept of a model itself?

Comment: @WS2: Actually it's hard to explain :)
Consider we have resume of 5 people (call theme A-E) like this:

/ A,B:[Programming, Dutch Language]
/ C:[Programming, Team Working, Dutch Language]
/ E,F:[Team Working, Dutch Language].
The A, B and C form a group X together and  C, D and E form another group, say Y. 
We want to find a specific resume for group  X which contain common abilities of its members. So, a "general" and "specific" resume would contain "Programming" but not "Dutch Language". Since "Dutch language" although is a share ability among A,B,C; it also is a share ability in group Y.

Comment: @MostafaDehghani So I've got five widgets A to E. A & B are red and yellow; C is red, yellow, and blue; D & E are blue and yellow. Now what is it we need to describe?

Comment: @WS2, 
Considering that A, B and C in the same group, we need an as unique as possible colour which indicates the group's member colour. Here, "red" is that colour. I mean "yellow" is also shared, but it's not unique colour among groups. So, I need an adjective which describes this property of "red". Assigning red to group X makes the group X specified from other groups (not like yellow which is also common in group Y) and also this assignment is general enough to cover the share colours of group X member.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "archetype" and "prototype"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23918/what-is-the-difference-between-archetype-and-prototype)

Comment: Do you really need a single word for this? The title seems a bit contradictory. Are you looking for an ['autantonym'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-antonym)?

Comment: @MostafaDehghani The *red possessors*?

Comment: @MostafaDehghani This question should not have been closed. You are looking for the term "family resemblance"

Comment: @MostafaDehghani Adjective: "polythetic."

Answer (score 6):

*[Prototypical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prototypical)* seems like an appropriate adjective:

> adjective: having the typical qualities of a particular group or kind of person or thing : very typical

The [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prototype&allowed_in_frame=0) implies a specific pattern in a general class:

> c.1600, from French prototype (16c.) and directly from Medieval Latin
>   prototypus "original, primitive,"
>
> from Greek prototypon "a first or primitive form," noun use of neuter
>   singular of prototypos "original, primitive,"
>
> from protos "first" (see proto-) + typos "impression, mold,
>   ***pattern***" (see type (n.)). In English from 1590s as prototypon.
>
> ***Emphasis*** mine

---

www.merriam-webster.com

www.etymonline.com

Comment: Thank you, @Andrew Leach, I'd like to learn how you did that :-)

Comment: Four spaces at the start of a line turns on code-formatting. I removed a space.

Comment: or [archetypical](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23918/what-is-the-difference-between-archetype-and-prototype)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps a *[goldilocks](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/Goldilocks)* model

> [AS MODIFIER] Denoting or referring to the most desirable or advantageous part of a range of values or conditions (typically the center):
>
> *the planet is in the middle of what astronomers call the Goldilocks zone: a place that’s not too hot and not too cold*
>
> *he promises us a return to the Goldilocks economy—not too much deflation, not too much inflation*

*Oxford Dictionaries Online*